# Capistrano 3 use login shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I ve read this nice explanation of login/nonlogin, interactive/noninteractive shells http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/. But I found nowhere, how to run capistrano 3 in specific shell. I have tried options like:

```
set :pty, true # non-login, interactive but does not load .bashrc
set :default_shell, '/bin/bash --login'
set :shell, '/bin/bash --login'
```

but nothing helped. Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to get around this issue?

Comment: No, i am not working on that project anymore. So i stopped to looking for solution.

Comment: Do you really need specific shell?  In my case, my issue was resolved by using <<set :default_env, { path: "/home/ruby/ruby-2.2.0-64bit/bin:$PATH" }>> line in config/deploy.rb

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question, but the below shows how to open the SSHKit class and enable login shell, for capistrano.

```
# backend/sshkit.rb
module SSHKit
  class CommandMap
    class SuffixProvider
      def initialize
        @storage = CommandHash.new
      end 

      def [](command)
        @storage[command] ||= []

        @storage[command]
      end

      def to_s(command)
        self.[](command).join(" ")
      end
    end

    def [](command)
      cmd = []

      if prefix[command].any?
        prefixes = prefix[command].map{ |prefix| prefix.respond_to?(:call) ? prefix.call : prefix  }
        cmd.push(prefixes.join(" "))
      end

      cmd.push(@map[command])

      cmd.join(" ")
    end

    def suffix
      @suffix ||= SuffixProvider.new
    end
  end

  class Command
    def to_s
      [SSHKit.config.command_map[command.to_sym], *Array(args), SSHKit.config.command_map.suffix.to_s(command.to_sym)].compact.join(' ')
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can define SSHKit command maps to enable `bash --login` for a specific command.

```
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rvm].prefix("bash --login '")
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rvm].suffix("'")
```

Now you can use `:rvm` command like below.

```
execute :rvm, :use, '2.2.2', '--install'
# => bash --login 'rvm use 2.2.2 --install'
```

I've written a [blog post](https://hass-isnull.io/capistrano-and-sshkit/) which explains this further. I would however recommend you use the login shell only when you must require it.

Answer (score -1):

I have not found an answer for you...

But what I did was follow advice from [A word about PTYs](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/README.md#a-word-about-ptys):

> When Capistrano makes a connection it is a non-login, non-interactive shell. This was not an accident!

Maybe you need something that has been set in your **.bash_profile** as part of an interactive login? Move it to your **.bashrc** as that will be called by capistrano.

Comment: I already tried to insert code into .bashrc, .profile, .bash_profile, but nothing helped.

Comment: bash_profile and profile should definately not be being called! but bashrc will be: to confirm that is the case, output your change in bashrc in a task and check the output, eg: task :test do o roles(:app) do execute "echo ${PATH}" end end shows me that my path in .bashrc has been loaded.

Comment: I tested it already that way, created task to output my variable. But it is not working. If you think bashrc should be called and you tried it and is working, I will try to contact system admin, probably it is specific settings for this machine. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure who you are logging in as? put execute "whoami" to make sure?